# Netty-TCP-HTTP-MQTT design

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, sockets, netty

I am trying to write a server-side java application that can accept tcp, http and mqtt communication (receive and send/ MongoDB as storage). From research, we decided that it could be a jar application based on Netty and paho for mqtt. We have 3 project using three of these protocols, therefore I am trying to unify the connection module. They each have different protocol style, for example:

-tcp:   0102330123456700

-http:  HTTP POST /URL/count  {"id":"02","count":"01234567"}

-mqtt:  topic /02/count    {"count":"01234567"}

Since we are a bit short of time, i am running them three in a silly but quick way---3 different thread listening to 3 different ports.

```
public class ServerLauncher {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NettyRestServer nettyRestServer = new NettyRestServer();
    MqttServer mqttServer = new MqttServer();
    EchoServer echoServer =  new EchoServer();

    new Thread(nettyRestServer,"HTTP Listening").start();
    new Thread(mqttServer,"Mqtt Listening").start();
    new Thread(echoServer,"socket Listening").start();
}
```

}

My questions are:

1. Since they are all based on tcp, is there a good way to manage them all together without wasting thread resource? maybe running just one thread for listening one port. I only find examples of single protocol.
2. For data storage, is it an okey design to push all the incoming messages to a concurrentHashMap across all thread/channels. Finally with a another thread running scheduled task, storage this concurrentHashMap into MongoDB and reset. or maybe use queue instead of concurrentHashMap

Answer (score 0):

If you use Netty for all of these you can share the same `EventLoopGroup` for all servers which means all will share the same `Threads`.

Comment: Hi,Norman, I am actually read "Netty in Action" from you. Anyways, I have now rearranged this way. But I found very little netty-mqtt information except java docs. I wonder if there is any resource that i can go through

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use three threads to start Server. You can do all of these in only one ServerBootstrap. And put the logic in ChannelHandler.

Netty's ChannelPipeline can dynamicly change ChannelHandler when getting the connecttion.

```
  ctx.pipeline().addBefore(...)
  ctx.pipeline().addAfter(...)
  ctx.pipeline().remove(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Frio, I am now sharing on ServerBootstrap. However, pipeline will not recognize tcp, http or mqtt. does it mean that i will have to decide the protocol first, then choose which logic will be passed on.
`ctx.pipeline().addBefore(new ProtoclSelector())` 
this kind of arrangement?

Comment: You are right. I'm not sure if the mqtt is based on tcp, I will suppose it is based on the tcp stack.First of all, you need to wait for tcp connect like this:b.group(bossGroup,workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).childHandler(WebSocketServerInitializer).And then, you need to pre define a decoder that have been added to the WebScoketServerInitializer instance. The decoder is in charge of adding followed decoder and handler after reading the header bytes.